# Parse AndroidManifest attributes

Tags: php, android, android-manifest

I made a simple apk uploader with PHP, I want to parse manifest attributes form `AndroidManifest.xml` but I got the following errors, Any ideas !?

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in E:\AppServ\www\apkUploader\mainApi.php on line 21
```

***line 21 =*** `$versionName = $xml->xpath('/manifest/@android:versionName');`

***Source code :***

```
/* For Apk File */

if (($_FILES["mFile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.android.package-archive") || ($_FILES["mFile"]["type"] == "application/octet-stream"))
{
    if ($_FILES["mFile"]["error"] > 0)
      {
          echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["mFile"]["error"] . "<br />";
      }
    else
      {
          echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["mFile"]["name"] . "<br />";
          echo "Type: " . $_FILES["mFile"]["type"] . "<br />";
          echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["mFile"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
          echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["mFile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";
          error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
          $dom = new DOMDocument();
          $dom->load('AndroidManifest.xml');
          $xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
          $versionName = $xml->xpath('/manifest/@android:versionName');
          $versionCode =$xml->xpath('/manifest/@android:versionCode');
          $package = $xml->xpath('/manifest/@package');
          echo "VERSION NAME :".$versionName[0]->versionName."<br/>";
          echo "VERSION CODE :".$versionCode[0]->versionCode."<br/>";
          echo "VERSION PAC :".$package[0]->package."<br/>";
          if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["mFile"]["name"]))
            {
              echo $_FILES["mFile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
          else
            {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mFile"]["tmp_name"],
              "upload/" . $_FILES["mFile"]["name"]);
              echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["mFile"]["name"];
            }
      }
  }
else
  {
      echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);` does not return a valid object. This usually means that the file cannot be loaded or parsed.

Don't forget to check if there was an error :

```
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
if (!$xml)
{
    // An error occurred
}
```

Comment: +1, Thank you for mention it, how can I get the XML inside a apk file (kind of a zip file) for read it?

Comment: Well, I think you should post another question about this (I don't know the answer, sorry).